# Replacing/Remapping values in object array

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am pulling an array object from a mongoDB. The nodeJs code looks like this:

```
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {

    let searchOptions = {}
    
    if (req.query.name != null && req.query.name !== ''){
        searchOptions.name = new RegExp(req.query.name, 'i')
    }

    try {
        const persons= await Person.find(searchOptions)

         res.render ('persons/index', { 
            persons: persons,
            searchOptions: req.query
         })
         
    } catch {
        res.redirect('/')
    }
})
```

The database data has the following structure:

```
[
  {
    _id: 607d83d6877c33156c54a555,
    name: 'person1',
    dob: 2020-11-29T00:00:00.000Z,
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: 607d9f15552e7931b8381170,
    name: 'person2',
    dob: 2021-04-08T00:00:00.000Z,
    __v: 0
  }
]
```

When I display `<div><%= person.dob %></div>` in my browser, the values are formatted as follow:

```
Sun Nov 29 2020 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Mitteleuropäische Normalzeit)
```

I am looking for a way to display `person.dob` in a more readable way, that's why I want to replace (or remap?) every `dob value` for each person with something like (YYYY-MM-DD) and then pass it on:

```
     res.render ('persons/index', { 
        persons: persons,
        searchOptions: req.query
     })
```

Would it be best to replace the existing date values or create a new array object and how would I implement this the easiest way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Array.map() function to do this pretty easily.

```
res.render ('persons/index', {
    persons: persons.map(dob => format(dob)),
    searchOptions: req.query
})
```

Here's the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This doesn't seem to work (Error: "Malformed arrow function parameter list"). Is the object key person.dob not a valid parameter for .map()?

Comment: After double checking your data, I think it should just be persons.map(dob => format(dob)). It only becomes person.dob after you've done something like "for person in persons".